# from import from python in reticulate

Tags: r, reticulate

Any way to do the `from - import` from Python in Reticulate without having to import the whole module?

example: `from tensorflow import keras`

I know about the solution below, but it imports the whole module anyway...

```
keras <- import('tensorflow')$keras
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
keras <- import('tensorflow.keras')
```

In general in python:

```py
from abc import xyz as uvw
```

means in R

```r
uvw <- import('abc.xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if you are writing your r code in an rmd file, wouldn't you be able to do it directly in a python chunk like this:

```
python

from ... import ...
```